# How to query daily counts using localtime where data is in GMT

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I need a sql server query to get daily rows counts for a given month.  My timestamp is stored in GMT but my month needs to be defined by the client in localtime.   This code seems to work but is sooo nasty and will likely become slow as the table grows even with EntryDate as an index.  Is there an easier way?  The clients will be in various timezones so I can't create an additional column.  Month/year/timezone are hard-coded in this example but would be passed over via parameters to C# code execute the SQL.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.  Would it be a lot faster to pass the offset in hours and offset the dates using that?

```
select CreateDate=DATEPART(DAY, EntryDate AT TIME ZONE 'Greenwich Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'), Items=count(1) 
   from TestTable1 
   where year(EntryDate AT TIME ZONE 'Greenwich Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time') = 2018  
     and month(EntryDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Greenwich Standard Time') = 9 
   group by DATEPART(DAY, EntryDate AT TIME ZONE 'Greenwich Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time') 
   order by 1
```

Any ideas appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you convert to local time. It does not include any of the row count logic.

```
DECLARE @V_UTC_DATETIME DATETIME
  SET @V_UTC_DATETIME='2012-12-03T08:48:52'
  SELECT @V_UTC_DATETIME AS UTC_DATETIME,
DATEADD(hh,((DATEDIFF(ss,@V_UTC_DATETIME,GETDATE())-DATEDIFF(ss,
@V_UTC_DATETIME,GETUTCDATE()))/3600),
@V_UTC_DATETIME) AS LOCAL_DATETIME
```